# Is it possible to create multiple gh-pages for the subdirectories within one repository?

Tags: github

I'm wondering if I can create a different gh-pages for the subdirectories within one single repository? I tried pushing a subdirectory to gh-pages but it takes the repository's link.

For example:

- Repo

  - Folder1
  - Folder2

Pushing Folder1 to gh-pages takes the user.github.io/Repo link instead of its own.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What would a correct link be?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. GitHub only provides one `gh-pages` site per repository.

However, if you have different versions of the code on different branches for testing, that can be done locally.

If you are wanting to display more than a one-page site, that is possible by having multiple `.html` files within the directory.